# Else being executed while it shouldn't be

Tags: java

I'm currently writing a minecraft plugin in java.
But i'm facing an issue, an else statement is being fired while it shouldn't

I'm checking if a player is in a region called "safezone"
This will return true, i debugged this. However it fires the else Both if and else statements

I'm unsure why this is happening, and can't quite put my finger on it.

Here's my method

```
@EventHandler
public void entityDamageEvent(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
    if (event.getEntity() instanceof Player) {
        Player attacker = (Player) event.getDamager();
        Player player = (Player) event.getEntity();
        Location location = player.getLocation();

        WorldGuardPlatform platform = com.sk89q.worldguard.WorldGuard.getInstance().getPlatform();
        RegionContainer container = platform.getRegionContainer();

        if (location.getWorld() != null) {
            RegionManager regionManager = container.get(BukkitAdapter.adapt(location.getWorld()));
            ApplicableRegionSet set = regionManager.getApplicableRegions(BukkitAdapter.asBlockVector(location));
            for (ProtectedRegion r : set) {
                if (r.getId().equals("safezone")) {

                    player.sendMessage("true");
                    attacker.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Can't attack palyers here");
                } else {
                    attacker.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You're now in combat, logging out will cost you!");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You're now in combat, logging out will cost you!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'll leave the contents of the set as well

```
ProtectedRegion{id='arena', type='CUBOID'}
ProtectedRegion{id='safezone', type='CUBOID'}
```

Comment: You are iterating over ProtectedRegion which has set data for both the condition. Of course it fires for both the cases.

Comment: You have two regions that you're looping through. The first one isn't a safezone and will trigger the else block. The second one is a safezone and will trigger the if block. I'm guessing the safezone would override the arena? In that case, you could define a boolean on whether or not the user is in a safe zone and loop through the set until you find a safezone. If you find one, set the boolean to true, break the loop, and then fire your if block. If you don't find one at the termination of the loop, fire your else block.

Comment: Also I have a doubt how ApplicableRegionSet works. Does it return the player's current region? Does it check all the blocks in the world or a limited area?

Answer (score 0):

For all the ProtectedRegion objects for which `r.getId.equals("safezone")` is false, the else block will be executed.
For example: if you have a total of 10 ProtectedRegion objects and there are 6 objects whose `id` instance variable is not `"safezone"`, your else block will run 6 times

This is assuming your id instance variable is of type String

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by saving the regions to a List and checking with .contains("safezone")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).